# Qt Layouts in QCreator

Tags: qt, qlayout

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how QLayouts work. Basically, I start a MainWindow project, then add a new QWidget-based form where I lay out QLineEdits and QLabels in a horizontal layout for use as a dotted-quad input editor. All looks well in preview.

Then I add a QWidget to my MainWindow class, and promote it to my DottedQuadEdit class. Looks OK if it's not in a layout, but once added to a layout it collapses to zero size.

I've fiddled with all the various size policies, size settings, layout configurations, all with no success. The promoted class is fine until it lands in a layout, then gets squished away to invisibility when added to a layout.

I've explored many tutorials, and the Qt documentation, but just haven't turned up a decent explanation of how layouts actually work.

Comment: I wrote the layout tutorial on StackOverflow. you can see them here: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/qt/9380/about-using-layouts-widget-parenting#t=201704031930582621633. Maybe you can give us more code about what you did and we can talk about it. If you have any troubles with my tutorials you can ask me questions too.

Answer (score 0):

As Gabriel mentioned, showing your code will help. My guess is that your `QWidget` has no minimum size defined in Qt Creator, which means that it can legitimately collapse to a zero size. The minimum size parameters are part of the attributes that you can edit for every `QWidget`; experiment with those to give it a size that makes sense. Then you can also play with whether that size is minimum, preferred, expanding, and so on.

When you place it independently (i.e. not in a layout), it keeps the size you give it when you dragged it out. Once you place it into a layout, the layout manages its size, and without a minimum, the layout is free to resize it all the way down to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the layout of the QWidget - based form in which you have added QLineEdits and QLabels? You need to specify the layout for the form as well.